# Combining mutate, across, and as_date('yyyymmdd') results in all NA

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate, across

I'm trying to combine mutate, across, and as_date, including the `format` argument in as_date. This is resulting in all `NA` values, as shown below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tis)

holidays(2023) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  set_names('holiday_date') %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rowname,values_from = holiday_date) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                #as_date                      # WORKS
                ~as_date(.,format="yyyymmdd") # DOESN'T WORK
  ))
```

This results in

```
# A tibble: 1 × 10
  NewYears MLKing GWBirthday Memorial Juneteenth Independence Labor  Columbus Thanksgiving
  <date>   <date> <date>     <date>   <date>     <date>       <date> <date>   <date>      
1 NA       NA     NA         NA       NA         NA           NA     NA       NA          
# ℹ 1 more variable: Christmas <date>
```

If I swap the commented out `as_date` line (labelled "`WORKS`") for the `~as_date` line ("`DOESN'T WORK`"), I get the expected result, sans the desired formatting:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 10
  NewYears   MLKing     GWBirthday Memorial   Juneteenth Independence Labor      Columbus   Thanksgiving
  <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>       <date>     <date>     <date>      
1 2023-01-02 2023-01-16 2023-02-20 2023-05-29 2023-06-19 2023-07-04   2023-09-04 2023-10-09 2023-11-23  
# ℹ 1 more variable: Christmas <date>
```

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here and how to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you used `pivot_wider()` and then applied `mutate(across(...))`, the column types got converted to character format, hence the problem with the date conversion with `as_date` with the format argument.

instead, use `mutate(across(...))` directly after `pivot_wider()` to convert the columns to character, and then use another `mutate(across(...))` to convert them to dates. you can specify your own desired format.

```
holidays(2023) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  set_names('holiday_date') %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rowname, values_from = holiday_date) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as_date)) %>%  # Convert to dates without format
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~as_date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d")))  # Convert to dates with the desired format
```

Comment: Thanks @jeffreyohene. That makes sense. I'll accept your answer. Any chance you can just modify the ```format = ``` portion to give the desired format (yyyymmdd with no dashes)? I keep getting dashed date results even when using ```"yyyymmdd"```.

Answer (score 1):

The `format` argument in the function `as_date` (as well as in the `as.Date` from `base`) is to parse the input values into a date class value, it's not the format for the desired output. That would be the `format` function but that one would turn your data class values into character.

Just by using `as.character` instead of `as_date` the format would be the desired `"yyyymmdd"` (written `"%Y%m%d"`) but it would be a character and not a date object.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be seen if you look at the data type of the output of `holidays(2023)`:

```
typeof(holidays(2023)[[1]]) # [1] "double"

holidays(2023)[[1]] - 3 # [1] 20230099
```

Even though it *looks* like a date, or maybe even a string, it's actually just a number; 20230102 is 20 million, 230 thousand and 102, hence subtracting three gives you 20230099.

The solution is to convert it into a character, and then convert it *back* into a Date (the date format in R is a type of double, under the hood, but that's a conversation for a different time).

This can all be done quite succinctly with `enframe()` and the `values_fn` argument of `pivot_wider()`:

```
enframe(holidays(2023)) |>
  pivot_wider(values_fn = \(x) as.character(x) |> as.Date(format = '%Y%m%d'))
```

Comment: Oh hai, Mark! You are the expert! ;-) Sorry, couldn't help myself, given your photo. Thanks for this great answer. I hadn't ever looked into the ```values_fn``` argument of ```pivot_wider```. I'd also never encountered the ```enframe``` function before. I will certainly start incorporating these into my workflows. A question: what is ```|>``` doing here? That isn't an operator I've encountered before. Is it just another way of writing a pipe (```%>%```)?

Comment: |> is what is known as the native pipe. It's basically the same as the magrittr pipe (%>%) but included with r